# Connect to iis7 web site with ip?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I got 2 pages on my iis7. None of them got a domain addy yet. So I wonder how I could connect to them with the server ip somehow?

like if i got all in the files in wwwroot and I can access to the web site like this..
http://111.MYIP/default.aspx

appreciate any help I get thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do that.

Make sure you add your ASP.Net source to the "Default" website and that port 80 is not blocked by any firewalls.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(WS.10).aspx

> During IIS 7 installation, a default Web site configuration is created in the \Inetpub\Wwwroot directory on your Web server. You can either use this default directory to publish your Web content, or create a directory at a file system location of your choice.

Comment: My thing is that I got 2 sites and can not put both in the default. I will check the firewall to open the port tho.

Comment: What i do in that situation is to add new sites as new applications under the default website.  ASP.Net has a nice way of virtualizing the application root so http://localhost/example.com/ can be your test root but can be deployed to http://example.com/ without any changes to the code.

Comment: thanks for the link. I just forgot to add the port
it was like http://111.MYIP:PORT/default.aspx

Comment: Nice. Do you add new sites or virtual directory in the default site?

Comment: virtual directories, or more specifically new application folders in the default site.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line in your hosts file which represents the name of your domain, but point to your local host (127.0.0.1). More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file